# Script to backup home directory creating a compressed tar file in the /var/local directory

Tags: scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
tar -czvf backup.tar.gz  /home/administrator
```

Having problems with making sure the file is created in the `/var/local`   directory.

Answer (score 3):

Change it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
tar -czvf /var/local/backup.tar.gz  /home/administrator
```

Now it will be created in /var/local directory.

Comment: It ddnt create a backup in the location getting error

Comment: tar: Removing leading  '/' from member names

Comment: @jackotonye the location /var/local must exist to create a file there

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
tar -czvf /var/local/backup.tar.gz  -C /home/administrator/
```

Try this it should solve your problem.

You can use the -P switch as well.